# How to use a Vimeo API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, vimeo

I have already installed Composer. Im trying to run my vimeo api and get the result in the localhost. but it doesn't work, my php file will keep loading on the chrome and not responding. Can anyone please help

FYI this is the API link that i desire to run, "Getting Started":
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php
      //echo "fHello";


      
      require 'C:\www\testing.php';
      use Vimeo\Vimeo;

      $client = new Vimeo("{191e3071cfe69f8d48424621488a76b06c2bd19b}",
      "{YDxiujy1nd+s4/w9q4xRq0O1dX0OEu1xs7Fhdce5/H69HJSDWXrYvPV8Y4RHFVPUgMIGsw9fr2+QHzpHPj/x9cmva8sjRA5aBppYDAbZa9Rj/N1/rPWDDJHmgFJ2WI8Y}",
      "{c725c21e7827b252d4574be2cbe1220c}");

      $client->request($uri, array(
        'name' => '{new video title}',
        'description' => '{new video description}',
      ), 'PATCH');

      echo 'The title and description for ' . $uri . ' has been edited.';


       ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Sorry im a new developer in php, may I know where to check the error logs? Becoz when I try to run on chrome, there is no respond in my cmd localhost

Comment: The error log location depends on which web server you're using. Once you have that you can search for "error logs on <web server name>"

Comment: But what if I'm using the local host and open in browser?

Comment: You have to have a local web server running.

Comment: Alright i see, so Xampp is one of the example right?

Comment: XAMPP has an Apache web serve, so that is correct.